# Unable to import libgdx top level project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

My Eclipse workspace only has my platform specific projects in it. For some reason the setup.jar didn't make the top level project available for Eclipse. What do I need to do to import it into Eclipse?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of the setup.jar, it creates a Gradle-based project, so you need the Gradle plugin installed in Eclipse, and then import it as a Gradle project. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You have two variants: install Gradle integration plugin or generate Eclipse project files in Advanced option in gdx-setup.jar.